# Can connect to all but one file share; ping works

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machines, file-sharing

I'm running Windows 10 32 bit in a VirtualBox machine.  I'm connected to our company's domain, and I can connect to the internet and most file shares.  I can connect to our domain controller (also runs DHCP), but can't connect to one server.  I can ping that server, though, so the physical connection is there.  I can also connect to that server via the File Explorer on the host machine (not the VM).

We had this problem once before and had to call remote support, but then it was almost a 30-second fix.  Do you guys have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Is the host machine Windows 10? Are there any errors in the event logs? This will be difficult for us to figure out with just the information you have provided.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but if you *do* have an IT support team for this domain that has already solved this problem previously (and rather easily at that), it would probably wise to contact them.  When/if that happens, ensure that you annotate what they did to fix it.

Comment: @EBGreen The host machine is Windows 10.  It's a Lenovo laptop, connected via wifi, if that helps.  Let me know if I can post any more info.

Comment: @Run5k Yes, it'll probably take some time, but I'll make sure to update this if we end up going that route.

Comment: Are there any errors in the event logs?

Comment: Understood and as I said before, we are always glad to help.  But as a manager with oversight over three different domains, if one of my end-users was trying to troubleshoot problems on my network via Stack Exchange without even asking my team first, we would probably have a polite mentoring session afterwards.

Comment: @EBGreen None pop up after trying to connect, but there's one a couple hours ago from DistributedCOM.  Probably unrelated, I'm thinking.

Comment: @Run5k Yes, I've talked with my manager (the IT admin here).  I'm in the process of setting up this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after 4 hours more of research, it was a problem with the Windows update 1709 and later, where SMB v1.0 is no longer supported by default.  Thanks https://superuser.com/a/1273689/371208.

1. Open the start menu and search `Turn Windows Features on or off` from the Control Panel
2. Check the box next to `SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support`.
3. Click OK and restart the computer